# Cocos2d CCLayer.scale

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I am in process of making a small game, where the main Gameplay Layer is being zoomed in and out based on a number of parameters. This is done by setting the .scale attribute to a fraction of 1. Works well.

I have a problem, however, that when calling `[[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];` from any of the child nodes, I get a scaled window size, which kinda sucks :) Is there any way around this apart from multiplying all my off-screen checks by the scale fraction plus one?

**Here is an example**

I am creating a CCLayer and placing Sprites on it. All the sprites have a static variable with the screen size during initialization, basically

```
static CGRect screenRect; //stored as a static variable for performance reasons
...
-(id)init{
    ...
    // make sure to initialize the screen rect only once
    if (CGRectIsEmpty(screenRect)){
        CGSize screenSize = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];
        screenRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, screenSize.width, screenSize.height);

        CCLOG(@"Screen Size during init: %f, %f", screenSize.width, screenSize.height);
    }
}
```

I then have a check when the sprite is moving around whether it is off the screen, and if so, I take it automatically to the opposite side:

```
if(newPosition.x > screenRect.size.width){
    newPosition.x = 0;
}else if(newPosition.x < 0){
    newPosition.x = screenRect.size.width;
}

if(newPosition.y > screenRect.size.height){
    newPosition.y = 0;
}else if(newPosition.y < 0){
    newPosition.y = screenRect.size.height;
}
```

All works very well and as expected. However, if I change the `scale` property of the parent CCLayer then offscreen positioning "scales" together with the layer, which is kinda weird. So if I set the `CCLayer.scale = 0.5f;` then it appears as though the off-screen boundaries have moved "inside" the phone screen as well. I want to avoid this. How?

Comment: Hi. I checked it. Its working fine for me. I scaled my layer and checked for winSize. Its giving the right value. I am not able to understand how you are calling from child nodes? Its same code everywhere.

Comment: Hi, thanks! I have just added an example with code!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After talking to quite a few developers, the off-bounds check need to take scaling into account, i.e.

```
newPosition.x > screenRect.size.width/CCLayer.scale
```